# Is the subspace generated by complete othogonal subspaces closed?

Tags: general-topology, inner-products

$E$ is a vectorial space equipped with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. $(E_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of complete pairwise orthogonal subspaces.

**Is the subspace $V$ generated by the union of the $E_i$ closed?**

I ask the question as I'm reading a French book on Topology and functional analysis. And in a theorem it is mentionned *$V$ is the closed subspace generated par the union of the $E_i$*. So I have issues to understand if $V$ is closed as a consequence of the hypothesis or if it is an additional hypothesis.

And I'm not to able to prove that $V$ is closed based on the other hypothesis...

Comment: It's an additional hypothesis. "The closed subspace generated by..." means "the smallest closed subspace containing..."

Comment: Thanks David. And the "closed subspace generated by..." is the standard English wording to designate "the smallest closed subspace spanned by the ..."?

Comment: I've never seen "smallest closed subspace spanned by...". For good reason - "spanned by" already specifies _one_ subspace. Another valid standard wording is "the closed subspace spanned by..."